# How to take input in java like this way?

Tags: java

How to take the this input in 5x5 char matrix in java ?

```
.*...
.....
.....
...*.
.....
```

Comment: what way is that?

Comment: i have to type this and it will stored in the matrix 5x5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767873/reading-a-text-file-character-by-character-into-a-2d-array-in-java see this question

Comment: Will you be typing each character of input, so it needs to take input 25 times? Or is the input one 25-character-long String?

Comment: input is like i will enter 5 char the Enter the 5 char then Enter like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method, taking the user's input one line at a time:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Matrix{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        char[][] matrix = new char[5][5];  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nInput 5x5 char matrix one line at a time:\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
                String row = in.nextLine();
                for(int j=0;j<matrix[i].length;j++){
                    matrix[i][j]=row.charAt(j);
                }
        }

        System.out.println("\nOutput:\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
Input 5x5 char matrix one line at a time:

.*...
.....
.....
...*.
.....

Output:

.*...
.....
.....
...*.
.....
```

Comment: Might need to add some validation, e.g. line length and valid chars, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll consider including it. Thanks for the +1.